# Sticky footer jumps up on mobile screen

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

In my web app I have a sticky footer for small screens. The issue is that the sticky footer jumps up and down depending upon the state of the keyboard.

I am looking for it to be overlay by the mobile keyboard. Here is the css for the sticky footer

```
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
height: 85px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

Any workarounds for this?

Comment: I think that this comes because the keyboard makes the viewport less tall to make place for the keyboard. You can ofcourse create your own keyboard. You can also try to detect the height of the viewport with css `meida queries` and than remove the sticky part from the footer when the screen height comes under a certain value

Comment: Is there a way to detect if the keyboard is open and then hide the footer and once the keyboard is closed show the footer?

Comment: I can't find anything like `if(keyboard) == active` but what you can do is that if the viewport height is smaller that the window height, you remove the sticky css code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to use something other than fixed for smaller/touch screens, since you would have to account for a number of different problems. This keyboard issue is one, turning the device to `viewport: landscape` is another. It can also cause an issue with scrolling, since touch devices don't render certain things until the scroll has completed (meaning elements can react differently depending on how quickly the user swipes their finger to scroll). It's better to make a site that is reliable most of the time instead of having to figure out and account for all the different possible circumstances.

Even for "desktop" devices, if you can do something without fixed positioning, do it. In those cases, using fixed positioning is more of a shortcut than a best practice.

There are a number of ways to create a "sticky" footer without using fixed positioning, and this will help to keep your site optimized for the best viewing experience on most devices. If you google 'sticky footer', you'll find a number of great options. Some are below.

- [Ryan Fait's CSS Sticky Footer](https://web.archive.org/web/20161220173953/http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)
- [CSS-Tricks sticky footer](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/)
- [Bootstrap sticky footer example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/)